# Indent on New Line between HTML/XML Tags

Tags: vimscript, indentation, filetype-html

I'm currently using

```
imap <silent> <C-c> </<C-X><C-O><C-X><Esc>F<i
```

as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130734/how-can-one-close-html-tags-in-vim-quickly) and [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_closing_an_HTML_tag) to close `<></>` tags of any kind with `<C-c>`, which works a treat.

However, I am stuck coming up with a way to enter a new line indented and have the closing tag on the line below automatically placed.

As follows (`|` being the cursor):

```
<body>|</body>
```

... hit `<CR>`...

```
<body>
    |
</body>
```

I notice this happens with just `<body><CR>` (no closing tag) but I cannot get it to behave as required.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Minor detail: `<C-c>` in insert mode has a subtle, but [potentially useful default behavior](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-C) that you may not want to overwrite.

Comment: A similar question has been asked on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130734/how-can-one-close-html-tags-in-vim-quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Plugin *xml.vim* by Rene de Zwart ([github](https://github.com/othree/xml.vim), [#1397](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1397))

This plugin defines two relevant insert mode mappings `>` and `;;`. They work as following:

1. When you have already `<body>|</body>`, type `>`.
2. When you have `body`, type `;;`.

For both you should end up with:

```
<body>
    |
</body>
```

Similar insert mode behavior are provided by the plugins

1. **xmledit** by *Devin Weaver* ([github](https://github.com/sukima/xmledit), [#301](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301)):

   > When in insert mode and you finish a tag
   >   (pressing `>`) the tag will be completed. If you press `>` twice, it will
   >   complete the tag and place the cursor in the middle of the tags on it's own
   >   line (helps with nested tags).
2. **Closetag** by alvan ([github](https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag)) (Based on xml.vim)

   > ```
   > <table|
   > ```
   >
   > Now you press `>`, the content will be:
   >
   > ```
   > <table>|</table>
   > ```
   >
   > And now if you press `>` again, the content will be:
   >
   > ```
   > <table>
   >     |
   > </table>
   > ```
   >
   > The following tags will not be closed:
   >
   > ```
   > <area>, <base>, <br>, <col>, <command>, <embed>, <hr>, <img>, 
   > <input>, <keygen>, <link>, <meta>, <param>, <source>, <track>, <wbr>
   > ```
3. **HTML AutoCloseTag** by Michael Sanders ([#2591](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2591)) with remapping of `<CR>`:

   > ```
   > ino <buffer> <silent> < <><left>
   > ino <buffer> <silent> > <c-r>=<SID>CloseTag()<cr>
   > ino <buffer> <expr> <cr> <SID>Return()
   > ```

   `Return()` remaps `<cr>` to `<cr><cr>\<up>` which does no autoindentation. Following patch changes this:

   ```
   --- orig_html_autoclosetag.vim  2018-12-03 10:57:54.000000000 +0100
   +++ html_autoclosetag.vim   2018-12-03 10:57:10.000000000 +0100
   @@ -24,7 +24,7 @@
    fun s:Return()
       let tag = s:GetCurrentTag()
       return tag != '' && match(getline('.'), '</'.tag.'>') > -1 ?
   -               \ "\<cr>\<cr>\<up>" : "\<cr>"
   +               \ "\<cr>\<esc>O" : "\<cr>"
    endf

    fun s:InComment()
   ```

   Now you would enter `<body><cr>` to get the desired result.

Comment: How did I miss that one, works a treat, thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Plugin *vim-ragtag* by Tim Pope ([github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag), [#1896](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896))

This plugin defines following insert mode mappings which are useful after you have only typed `body`:

```
<C-X><Space>  <foo>^</foo>                              *ragtag-CTRL-X_<Space>*
<C-X><CR>     <foo>\n^\n</foo>                          *ragtag-CTRL-X_<CR>*
<C-X>/        Last HTML tag closed                      *ragtag-CTRL-X_/*
```

However, it does not provide a mapping to change `<body>|</body>` to `<body>\n|\n</body>`.
On the other side, the mappings can be considered less intrusive.

Answer (score 2):

#### Plugin *splitjoin.vim* by Andrew Radev ([github](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim), [#3613](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3613)) for Normal Mode

If you want to change the style afterwards in normal mode, the plugin `splitjoin.vim` makes this possible with the mapping `gS`:

> The idea of this plugin is to introduce a single key binding (default: `gS`) for
>   transforming a line like this:
>
> ```
> <div id="foo">bar</div>
> ```
>
> Into this:
>
> ```
> <div id="foo">
>   bar
> </div>
> ```

The other direction is also possible with `gJ` when the cursor is on the opening or closing tag.

Comment: This looks like a great plugin in general, nice!

Comment: Yes, I agree this plugin is quite useful in many circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

#### Plugin Lexima [Rules for HTML & Templates](https://github.com/deathlyfrantic/lexima-template-rules)

The plugin [lexima.vim](https://github.com/cohama/lexima.vim) provides smart behaviour when entering an opening expression, pressing `<backspace>` or `<CR>`.

By default rules e.g. for `(,[,{` exist. However, someone else has written a few rules for html/xml and template languages such as jinja and has published them in a separate github repository under the title *lexima-template-rules*:

https://github.com/deathlyfrantic/lexima-template-rules

The relevant rules are described as following:

> ```
> Before                      Input                   After
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |                           <                       <|>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <|> or <|/>                 <Backspace>             |
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <tag>| or <tag/>|           <Backspace>             <tag|> or <tag|/>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <tag foo="bar"|>            /                       <tag foo="bar"/>|
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <tag|/>                     /                       <tag/>|
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <tag>|</tag>                <Enter>                 <tag>
>                                                         |
>                                                     </tag>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Together with the mapping already used by OP using `inoremap`

```
❯ cat ~/.vim/vimrc
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
inoremap <silent> <C-c> </<C-X><C-O><C-X><Esc>F<i
```

You would type `<body><C-c><CR>`.

Answer (score 1):

### Plugin *emmet-vim* by Yasuhiro Matsumoto ([github](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim), [#2981](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981))

This plugin is quite powerful. Unfortunately, there is only a global switch to insert newlines for all childless tags:

```
let g:user_emmet_settings = {
\ 'html' : {
\     'block_all_childless' : 1,
\   }
\ }
```

Then you can type

```
body<C-y>,
```

to get the desired result.

Related issues on github are [#378](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/issues/378) and [#270](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/issues/270).

You can merge multi-line tags into a single line with

```
<C-y>m
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Plugin *UltiSnips* by Holger Rapp ([github](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), [#2715](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715)) and [Honza's Snippet Repository](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets)

You find in honza's snippet repository [most html](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/html.snippets) tags as a trigger word. This means following works for those:

```
body<tab>
```

expands to a predefined style (inline or multi-line):

```
<body>
    |
</body>
```

If you do not agree, you can easily customize the default style. If you need both styles you need two different trigger words.

Furthermore, two general purpose trigger words are defined `t` and `ti`:

1. Block style:

   ```
   t<tab>body<tab>
   ```
2. Inline style:

   ```
   ti<tab>body<tab>
   ```